# Android Emulator OpenGl error when running the application

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-emulator

When running a application in the Android Emulator I got the following error

> **Error:**
>
> [2014-08-20 13:15:29 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glActiveTexture:145
>   error 0x500

What does the above error mean and how to get it fixed.